# How to convert string to SQL Query

Tags: ballerina

I have a requirement to convert a query in the string type to sql:ParameterizedQuery because I have to read the query from a file and execute that query against a mysql:Client.

Need to convert this to sql:ParameterizedQuery

```
string qry = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, gender, dob FROM patient";
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't directly initialize the string to the parameterized query as this is an object type. We need to set the `strings` field of that parameterized query.

```
string qry = "SELECT id, FirstName, LastName, gender, dob FROM patient";
sql:ParameterizedQuery queryString = ``;
queryString.strings = [qry];
```